# Cannot correctly simplify a boolean function!

Tags: boolean-algebra

\begin{align}
(A+B)\cdot(A\cdot C)+B'C&=A+BC+B'C\\
&=A+C(B+B')\\
&=A+C(0)\\
&=A
\end{align}

I wanted to simplify the above stating problem, the answer is supposed to be A+C but here I mess something up, can you guys point me to the right direction,

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that B+B' = 0?

Answer (score 2):

The step (B + B') is not correct since whatever the value B has, B' will be the opposite, meaning that the sum will always be '1'.

Answer (score 2):

If B' is actually "not B", (B + B') is always 1.

B = 0, B' = 1 => B or B' = 1 or 0 = 1

B = 1, B' = 0 => B or B' = 0 or 1 = 1

Then, the boolean function is equal to A + C according to the third line.

Answer (score 2):

(B + B') is in fact always equal to 1. Indeed, when B is 0, B' is 1. 1 + 0 = 1. Here is the mistake.